# How to decompose the relation R(a,b,c,d,e) whith following FDs into BCNF?

Tags: normalization

I have  a FDs

- `ABC->DE`
- `AB->D`
- `DE->ABCE`
- `E->C`

My trial :

**Step 1 :**

- `A+ = A`
- `B+ = B`
- `C+ = C`
- `D+ = D`
- `E+ = EC`
- `AB+ = ABD`
- `ABC+ = ABCDE`
- `DE+ = ABCDE`

From above we get ABC,DE are our candidate keys

**Step 2 :**

1. `ABC -> DE` ==> no violation. bcoz abc is key.
2. `AB -> D` ==> violation.
3. `(ABD)(CE)`

   - in `(ABD) AB` is a candidate key. So it is in bcnf
   - in `(CE) C` is the candidate key. So it is in bcnf.

I have done here. But unable to process further. There is confusion after this that the step 2 is right or not. 
Can anyone solve this?

Comment: Hi. In step 1 you are applying an alogrithm (that you seem to assume that it is the only possible one because you don't give it) that requires a *cover*, not just some FDs that you "have". You don't give all your steps using it so we can't say why you missed a CK. Then in step 2 you are applying an algorithm (that you seem to assume that it is the only possible one because you don't give it) that uses *all* FDs that hold, not just some or those in some cover. You don't give all your steps using it so we can't say why you chose a bad decomposition. See hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Answer (score 1):

In your relation schema, there are three candidate keys: `ABC`, `ABE` and `DE`.

Since, for instance, `AB → D` violates the BCNF, we can decompose the original relation in:

```
R1(ABD) (with dependency AB → D and candidate key AB), and
R2(ABCE) (with dependencies E → C and ABC → E, and candidate keys ABC and ABE)
```

this is because we decompose in two relations, `AB+` and `R - (AB+) + AB`.

The second relation is still not in BCNF, since in E → C the attribute E is not a superkey.

So we can apply again this method to decompose R2 in:

```
R3(CE) (with dependency E → C and candidate key E)
R4(ABE) (with no dependency and candidate key ABE)
```

Both are in BCNF and the final decomposition is constituted by R1, R3, R4.

Finally, it is worth to note that the following dependencies:

```
DE → AB
ABC → E
```

are lost in the decomposition.

Comment: Thanks, @ypercubeᵀᴹ. Changed the answer.